# MySQL/Python/MAMP setup: almost made it, but obstacle at the end

Tags: python, mysql, mamp

(Hobbyist, not a pro, by the way.)

I have a working setup with MAMP. I have a big MySQL database and a lot of PHP written, and it all works great. Now I'd like to learn Python, and it seems that a good place to start would be within the framework of something I'm already familiar with, namely, my MAMP setup.

Without too much work I got python scripts running, but getting them to talk to the MySQL db seems a bit harder. I found some (apparently) good setup instructions at [Dream Conceptions](http://dreamconception.com/tech/how-to-install-mysqldb-mysql-python-on-mamp/), and I made it all the way to the end without incident. But when I enter the install_name_tool command, it complains that /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so doesn't exist.

I don't think I missed any steps in the instructions, but I could be wrong. A lot of what's out there on the net is about how to use Django, so I tried Django, but it wants to run its own server, and I don't want that. I want to start from a known, which is my own setup, which runs well. Plus I'd like to learn just Python to start with, and maybe add Django later.

Is _mysql.so supposed to be there already? Did I miss an obvious step?

***Edit:*** The output from `pip install mysql-python`:

`Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): mysql-python in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg`

Comment: can you post what is the output now when you run 'pip install mysql-python' ?

Comment: @shshank Added it to the post. Is that message telling me something? I suppose I could upgrade, but I just now installed it.

Comment: As the error says, _mysql.so file is not available in your site-packages.

Try downloading this file https://www.dropbox.com/s/qxi43qdds4c4ccr/_mysql.so

and put it at location `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/`.

Comment: @shshank Thanks for posting it to your dropbox account for me, but where does it usually come from? What's the standard way of getting it?

Comment: @shshank When I went to copy your _mysql.so to my site-packages folder, I noticed that there is a _mysql.so, but not directly in site-packages. It's actually in `site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg`. Should I just change the install_name_tool to point to that one?